# Change admin template in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the next simple model:

```
class Reseller(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        choices=(
            ('active', 'active'),
            ('inactive', 'inactive')))
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='Last Name')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='E-mail')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, editable=False)
```

I have automatically generated admin section for CRUD for this model. I want to add "Resend password" button (which will basically send new credentials to reseller) at the Update page but I don't know how. I know about extends functionality but I don't know how to apply it correctly. After clicking this page would be good to go to the same page but adding some kind of nitification 'New password has been sent'.

Also I don't know how to handle this new button action within Django admin. Any code snippets would be useful. Thanks

**UPDATE**
I created `change_form.html` and extends the original template

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block object-tools %}
{% if change %}
  <ul class="object-tools">
  <li><a href="reset_password/">Reset Password</a></li>
  </ul>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But I don't know how to treat this HTTP request. Also how can I pass any parameters? Should I create a form instead of button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to write Admin action, check [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) for more details.

**Update**: you should create something like this, you will get an action which can be applied to one or more selected resellers from resellers list page. You will end up with something like this:  [image]

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Reseller

class ResellerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    actions = ['reset_password']

    def reset_password(self, request, queryset):
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.password = genereate_new_passwd()
            sender.send(obj.email, obj.password)
            obj.save()
        self.message_user(request, "Passwords were resets for selected resellers successfully.")

    reset_password.short_description = "Resend Passwords for selected resellers"

admin.site.register(Reseller, ResellerAdmin)
```

**UPDATE 2:**
To provide a custom action in model change page, you need to customize the ResellerAdmin change_view() and provide
a custom template with some custom action.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Reseller

change_form_template = 'admin/myapp/extras/reseller_change_form.html'

class ResellerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if(comming from new action)
            # intercept the request post here, if it comes from your new button, do reset password
        else: 
            return super(ResellerAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
               form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Another approach is to customize the form by adding a Boolean field, and on save_model() check if that is True, then reset password and save, otherwise just save the object. In this case you dont have to provide custom template.

```
class ResellerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change and form.is_reset:
             #do reset password and send
        obj.save()

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ResellerAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.fields['is_reset'] = form.BooleanField()
        return form
```

The code above is not complete but to show the idea, more details on customizing ModelAdmin can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/)

Comment: this is a bit different to what I am asking. I have added a button by overriding `change_form.html` template, I added my button but I don't know how to handle the http request for this button. I think I need to add it to `urls.py` but what next?

Comment: @KennyPowers you are heading in the wrong direction, you shouldnt update admin pages with such specific functions.  I will update the answer for more explanation

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for ways of adding custom actions to a Django admin change page. I am not looking for actions that can be added to the dropdown box in the overview.