# Creating multiple objects of Model using one button in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to solve my problem, I was looking for answer but I can't find any solution.

Let's say I have a Model:

```
class AccessCode(models.Model):
    access_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Access code',
    unique=True, default=key_generator)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.access_code
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.access_code
```

There is only one field. What I like to do is to create additional button in admin panel and use this button to automatically create 100 AccessCodes in my database. 
So there are 2 questions:

1. How to create custom button in admin panel to perform some action with it?
2. How to automatically create 100 objects of some model with one step?

The key_generator is my custom function to generate random string as a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bulk_create` method introduced in Django 1.4,

```
AccessCode.objects.bulk_create([AccessCode() for i in range(100)])
```

However there are some problems with this approach, from django doc

> This has a number of caveats though:
>
> ```
> - The model’s save() method will not be called, and the pre_save and post_save signals will not be sent.
> - It does not work with child models in a multi-table inheritance scenario.
> - If the model’s primary key is an AutoField it does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as save() does.
> ```

To add action to admin page, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920485/2074398) with details how to do it.

Comment: Thank for your quick reply. I have a question to first point. What does exactly mean that save() method will not be called? Does it mean that those objects will not be saved in database? Would I have a possibility to operate on those objects (edit, delete)?

Comment: No, it will be saved in database, but the django model save method will not be called, this means if you have overridden save method with custom one to implement some custom logic on save, similar to this example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods then this logic will not apply with bulk_create